# how to change host name of azure web app service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am hosting an azure web app (PAAS), and I would like to rename the instance names to something meaningful for logging purposes. Currently the host name is something like RD000####.

I have looked at some links but the documentation seems very confusing, missing, vague, or not applicable to my purpose (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cie/2014/03/30/custom-hostname-for-windows-azure-paas-virtual-machines/, https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-viewing-and-modifying-hostnames/). Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: You are running in PaaS, this isn't really something you would be given control over. And how about if you have auto-scale enabled? It will still give names like that to the new instances it grabs from the pool.

Comment: @juunas thanks, if you can respond with an answer, I can mark it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as I mentioned in a comment, when you run in PaaS, you usually do not have access to these kinds of things. And even if you did, if you enable auto-scale, the new instances would still be named this random string of characters.

Technically the only point of those strings is to identify and separate the instances. When you run PaaS, those instances are just compute that can be thrown away and increased whenever, they are not given custom names.